# Should I wrap my function in if clause or use the opposite if condition and return prematurely?

Tags: javascript, performance

If the title isn't clear enough, which is probably the case, here's what I mean :

Is it better to do this :

```
function example() {
    if (condition) {
        //The whole function code
    }
}
```

or

```
function example() {
    if (!condition) {
        return;
    }
    //The whole function code
}
```

What is the cleanest way ?

Edit : I am not asking for your opinion. I'm wondering if there's any rule/convention/performance improvement.

Comment: They are considered equal - go with what you find better readable. Performance is absolutely equal. Go with the second if there would be too many levels of nesting otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second way, "golden path" style.

Since I started to write all of my code like that I've found it to be a lot easier to read later. Perform checks in the order that makes sense, and return as soon as anything unexpected happens.

Wrapping code in a new block also adds indentation, which is kind of a waste of screen real-estate.

Comment: Is it only a matter of preference, or is there any rule/convention/performance improvement ?

Comment: I started doing it after reading http://www.cimgf.com/zds-code-style-guide/, but I can't say that it has any effect beyond code readability.

Comment: My preference is for the second way also. Not for performance though. If you have got multiple conditions and tests in your function and you can return early it allows you to keep the indentation to the left. This makes it much easier to read and for another developer to understand. Nothing worse than 7 or 8 nested if /else statements.

Comment: I think this sums it up nicely: The goal here is to make the code on the left margin to be the “expected” code execution path and the code that is indented to be the exception. Consistency in this area is important to code readability.

Comment: personally I also prefer adding extra rows rather than nesting blocks, so at times I will have multiple returns for the same value but from different ifs, instead of writing one big if that's really hard to read.